# To display specific output for an input (from HTML) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-deployment

I just started with JavaScript and want to build a HTML page which accepts the input and the JavaScript takes the input from HTML and searches the database array and displays the specific output for each input.
Heres's the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="inputField" id="answer" placeholder="Enter the answer..." required>
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="mySubmit()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <link href'./script.js">

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the JavaScript :

```
var getInput = document.getElementById("answer").innertext;
console.log(getInput);
function mySubmit() {
    var text;
    var database = [
        {answer: "Apple", clue: "Steve Jobs"},
        {answer: "Mango", clue: "Fruit"}
    ];
    for(var i=0;i<database.length;i++){
        if(database[i].answer === getInput){
            text = database[i].clue;
            console.log(text);
        }
        else{
            text = "The answer is incorrect";
            console.log(text);
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innertext = text;
    }
}
```

The code should do as, if asks for user input e.g. Apple and give output on HTML as "Steve Jobs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things that weren't correct but overall your code was almost there.

First of all the 'innertext' you were looking for is actually 'innerText'.
Secondly, input elements don't have an innerText. They have an attribute 'value' instead.
Thirdly, to include javascript you'd use a script tag instead of a link tag.

Furthermore, I changed the binding of your function and did that in javascript using .addEventListener("click", ...) instead of in your HTML. But this is pretty much preference. Most of the time it will cause fewer errors though since if the script isn't loaded at all it won't try to find the specified function.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Webpage!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="inputField" id="answer" placeholder="Enter the answer..." required>
        <button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

Script

```
function getInput() {
    return document.getElementById("answer").value;
}

var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", mySubmit);

function mySubmit() {
    var text;
    var database = [
        {answer: "Apple", clue: "Steve Jobs"},
        {answer: "Mango", clue: "Fruit"}
    ];
    for(var i=0;i<database.length;i++){
        if(database[i].answer === getInput()){
            text = database[i].clue;
            console.log(text);
        }
    }

    if(!text) {
        text = "The answer is incorrect";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = text;
}
```

Comment: You code is wrong. You must break the `for` loop when you find the correct answer.  If you write `Apple` in the input field then you'll get `answer is incorrect`.

Comment: @ths Thank you, I've rewritten the code section that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your code, let me try to explain what you should use instead:

- To get what a user has typed in an `input` element, you should use the `value` attribute instead of the `innerText` attribute.

> `Node.innerText` is a property that represents the "rendered" text
>   content of a node and its descendants. As a getter, it approximates
>   the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the
>   element with the cursor and then copied to the clipboard. - [innerText MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)

- To get/set the text inside an element(other than `input`s), you should use the `textContent` attribute. [textContent MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- To attach a script file in a web page you should use the `script` tag by puttin the file path in the `src` attribute of the `script` tag: `<script src="path/to/javascript/file.js"></script>`
- Try to avoid using inline event listeners, instead you should use the `addEventListener` method.

Here's a runnable snippet to illustrate all what being said:

```js
// create reference to the input and the p#demo to get them when we need them
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  demo = document.getElementById('demo');
// add event listener to the button
btn.addEventListener('click', mySubmit);
// the event handler function
function mySubmit(e) {
  // prevent the default behaviour when the button is clicked
  e.preventDefault();
  // the value of the input must be fetched inside the event handler to get it every time the button is clicked
  var getInput = document.getElementById("answer").value.toLowerCase(),
    text = '',
    database = [{
      answer: "Apple",
      clue: "Steve Jobs"
    }, {
      answer: "Mango",
      clue: "Fruit"
    }],
    i = 0,
    l = database.length;
  for(; i < l; i++) {
    if(database[i].answer.toLowerCase() === getInput) {
      text = database[i].clue;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(text === '') {
    text = "The answer is incorrect";
  }
  demo.textContent = text;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="inputField" id="answer" placeholder="Enter the answer..." required>
    <button type="button" name="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` array helper to find the object that matches the input from your textfield. It'll return you the object as per your need. You can check the docs of find array helper on MDN.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="inputField" id="answer" placeholder="Enter the answer...">
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="mySubmit()">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Script**

```
function mySubmit() {
        let getInput = answer.value;
        var text;
        var database = [
            { answer: "Apple", clue: "Steve Jobs" },
            { answer: "Mango", clue: "Fruit" }
        ];
        text = database.find((data) => {
            if (data.answer === getInput) {
                return data;
            }
        });
        if (typeof text === 'object')
            text = text.clue;
        else
            text = "The answer is incorrect";
        demo.textContent = text;
    }
```

[Find array helper - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)